# postgres where equals any value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query where I filter a column based on a `where` clause, like so:

```
select * from table where col = val
```

What value do I set for `val` so that there is no filtering in the `where` clause (in which case the `where` clause is redundant)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What value do I set for val so that there is no filtering in the where clause?

It's impossible.

You might instead use

```
    query = "SELECT *  FROM TABLE"
    if val is not None:
        query += "  WHERE col = :val"
```

`None` is a common [sentinel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) value,
but feel free to use another.

---

Consider switching from `=` equality to `LIKE`.
Then a `%` wildcard will arrange for an unfiltered blind query.

```
    query = "SELECT *  FROM table  WHERE col LIKE :val"
```

Pro:

- You still get to exploit any index there might be on `col`, for values of `val` ending with a `%` wildcard.

Cons:

- The program behavior is clearly different, e.g. there might be a UNIQUE KEY on `col`, and the revised SELECT can now return multiple rows.
- Your data might contain wildcard characters, which now need escaping.
- Your users may have more flexibility now to pose queries that you didn't want them to.
- Any `%` characters that are *not* at the end of `val` may disable the index, leading to unexpectedly long query times / result set sizes.

Answer (score 2):

If col can't be null  you can use col=col?